# Digital Signature error in Excel / SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, digital-signature

I have a team that is co-authoring an Excel workbook. Occasionally, when the file is opened, users get a message the file can't be saved due to change(s): Digital signature(s).  (A photo is below.)

We do not have check-out enabled on the library (to allow co-authoring.) This happens on multiple workbooks. None of team members is implementing the Digital Signature feature in Office-365.  Workbooks do not have links to other workbooks, or links to outside data sources that could result in a security restriction. It doesn't happen all the time, but it happens frequently enough to be a real issue.

I have googled the living snot out of the Internet, and find ABSOLUTELY NOTHING on the subject.

Does anyone have any clue what is causing this to happen? (I have a theory that this is nothing to do with digital signatures, but rather it intends to reference digital fingerprint.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the owner of the file has  Digital signature(s) turned on. Please contact the file owner to check and disable this feature.

====================
If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: The owner, as well as all members on the team that have ever been impacted, have checked they do not have DigiSign enabled, as stated in the original post.